# How to add new row to grid without calling the addRow method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I have a hierarical grid with single save button to save new and updated parent and child rows. After making changes to any child row if I click  on add new row button, I get the new row but lose past changes. This is because addRow triggers rebinding of data and I lose my edits from other child rows. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to get a reference to the client-side object of the grid

   var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
2. Then you need to call the add method of the grid data source.

   grid.dataSource.add( { name: "Name", value: "2" } );

Taken from [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/add-row-in-kendo-grid)

There is a demo showing it in action [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@korchev/eRoSA)

Comment: this doesn't work because calling any method like `add`, `addRow` or `insert` on the `dataSource` triggers the rebinding of data and I lose my edits done in other child rows

Comment: Have you tried it? If you click "Add" in the middle of editing a cell in Kendo demo you will see that both vales stay and no ajax call (rebind) occurs.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Save the editted grid data in a tempArray

2 - Add new row

3- Rebind the grid with latest tempArray data